# How to set -dAutoRotatePages#/None in MikTeX

Tags: miktex, texniccenter, ghostscript

I'm using MikTeX 2.9 on Windows 7.

I understand one needs to tell GS explicitly not to auto rotate pages by supplying:

```
-dAutoRotatePages#/None
```

as parameter to `ps2pdf` (or `gswin32c`, as indicated [here](http://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=690703)).

Is there a way to also supply this parameter to `\MiKTeX-2.9\miktex\bin\latex.exe`? That is, can I run something like:

```
latex.exe [parameter] main.tex
```

and the produced DVI will not exhibit undesired autorotated pictures?

The reason for asking this is that I use Texniccenter, and the build setup (to DVI) only allows to pass options to `latex.exe`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Running `latex` only generates a `.dvi` file, it does not run GhostScript. That may be done by your editor in a 'build' system, which is where you would need to add the parameter. Exactly how do you run `ps2pdf` (the final stage of PDF creation using the `dvips` route)?

Comment: You have to set the parameter in your editor and not in MiKTeX. What Editor are you using? You'll find answers for TeXnicCenter and TeXWorks here: http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=pdf/pdfoutput  The option for `ps2pdf`is set in the same way.

Comment: @ Joseph, Herbert: I don't run ps2pdf at all. If I run pdflatex, the unwanted autorotation does not occur.

Comment: @ Joseph, Herbert: I don't run ps2pdf at all. If I want a PDF, I run pdflatex directly, and the unwanted autorotation does not occur. However, I want to produce a DVI file most of the time (for reasons of convenience) and would like to avoid autorotation there as well. Specficially, I have something like `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
Test.

\begin{figure}
 \includegraphics{myEPSFile}
\end{figure}

\end{document}`. All I do is run latex.exe on this file, and I would like to ensure the resulting DVI does not autorotate the graphics file.

Comment: @Johannes: `pdflatex` creates a `pdf` output and `latex` a `dvi`. The latter needs additional runs of `dvips` _and_ also `ps2pdf`. Nearly all editors allow the definition of scripts which does it all, see http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=pdf/pdfoutput#TXC for "LaTeX=>PS=>PDF". And, again, only `ps2pdf` which itself runs `ghostscript` can rotate parts of a page where it shouldn't ...

Comment: @Johannes:  A dvi doesn't contain a graphic, it contains only a link. Your request doesn't make sense, without the information how you are actually viewing the dvi (and you can see from the answer that nobody understood your question). Assuming you are using YAP: in the background it uses dvips + the miktex ghostscript and it is perhaps possible to add the `-dAutoRotatePages` but I would need an example of a problematic eps to make some tests.

Comment: @Herbert: Did you mean "the former needs additional runs of..." instead of "the latter needs additional runs"? I know that pdflatex creates a pdf and latex a dvi -- but not sure why we would need to call dvips and ps2pdf if we wanted a DVI.

Comment: @Ulrike: Thanks -- I know my questions was phrased badly, and I do lack knowledge of the Latex internals. I do use YAP, but I was (completely) unaware of what's happening in the background. I'm attaching two links two download the offending PS file (https://dl.dropbox.com/u/610154/myEPSFile.ps) and the corresponding TeX-File (https://dl.dropbox.com/u/610154/main.tex) in case you want to have a further look. Using YAP 2.9.4206, this gives the unintended rotation for DVI files; if I produce a PDF instead of a PS (or use Adobe's distiller) and call pdflatex, I get the desired unrotated output.

Comment: At first: your eps is not a correct eps file, but a ps-file. E.g. it doesn't start with `%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0`. Either generate directly correct eps or convert it with ghostscript. At second: YAP shows me the image in a portrait page with "horizontal" at the right, and the "vertical" at the bottom. Imho this is the correct (original) rotation of the graphic.

Comment: @Johannes: what do you want to do with a dvi? It is useless nowadays.

Comment: @Johannes: converting your ps file to eps with `ps2eps` and then using `ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages=/None <file>` gives a correct non rotated pdf.

Comment: @Ulrike: thanks for getting down to the internals of the graphic. A bit of background: the graphic was produced with R (a statistical computing software), and the displayed graphic (either in R itself or converted to PDF using Adobe's distiller) always appeared with the "horizontal" at the bottom. However, as I just learned from http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/grDevices/html/postscript.html and http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/grDevices/html/ps.options.html, in R one should set "ps.options(horizontal=FALSE)" to ensure produced PS-files get the "right" orientation.

Comment: Now, using these options, the resulting PS file is treated properly by Latex and displayed as intended. Wonderful -- I would never have been able to guess that there is orientation information set by R and embedded in the PS file that is ignored by some viewers and not ignored by others... Thanks to all offering their help.

Comment: @Herbert: I might in fact be out of touch with what the cutting edge is these days... The one reason why I use DVI is my workflow: I edit the source files (a complicated equation, typically), and then want to see the new output (to check the equation). So I compile, and then switch to the output file. If that file is a PDF, the old version needs to be closed (some editors do this automatically), the new updated version be opened (still, some editors do this automatically), and then I need to scroll (manually!) to the position in the document.

Comment: @Herbert, continued: At least to my knowledge, only DVI files (viewed by YAP for instance) allow to jump between source and output swiftly and painlessly. And there's the inverse search in YAP. So I need DVI for development -- to distribute or print documents, I use PDF of course.

Comment: And finally, I guess this question can be marked as solved. I would like to upvote some of the comments/commentators -- not sure though how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

### Install GhostScript

Make sure you have GhostScript installed and you have set PATH to its location. `gswin64c.exe` is for 64 bit version and `gswin32c` for 32 bit version. I use 64 bit version in this answer.

### Create a batch file

The following batch will compile your TeX input file 4 times, convert the resulting DVI to PS and finally convert the PS to PDF.

Save it as `combo.bat`, for example, in any directory. Set the PATH system variable to this batch location such that your operating system can find the batch when you call it later.

```
rem This is combo.bat. It takes a single argument which is a file name without extension

echo off

rem remove the previous PDF if any
del %1.pdf

rem compile 4 times
latex -draftmode -interaction=batchmode %1
latex -draftmode -interaction=batchmode %1
latex -draftmode -interaction=batchmode %1
latex %1

dvips -t unknown %1

gswin64c -r10000 -dCompatibilityLevel=1.5 -dAutoRotatePages=/None -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=%1.pdf %1.ps

rem remove unnecessary files
del %1.aux
del %1.dvi
del %1.log
del %1.out
del %1.ps
del %1.toc
del %1.nav
del %1.snm
```

### Configure TeXnicCenter

Configure TeXnicCenter as follows:

[image]

Comment: This will produce a PDF file (and probably one where the autorotation issue is fixed). However, will it also produce a "correct" DVI file?

Comment: @Johannes: Are you sure that `latex` will automatically rotate its content in DVI? I don't think `latex` does rotation automatically.

Comment: See the example files I posted in response to Ulrike's comment. Not sure which binary/program is automatically rotating content (latex/dvips/ps2pdf?) -- all I can tell is that in YAP, the final output appears rotated.