# Turn off autorotate in ps2pdf

Tags: winedt

I use WinEdt Build 20131031 (v. 8.1) 64-bit with Windows 7 and MikTeX. My slides have been made with the seminar package and contain a lot of eps files. I compile the tex document in the following order: LaTeX -> dvips -> ps2pdf.

My problem is that I want to turn off the autorotate in ps2pdf. Otherwise a number of slides that contain the eps plots are incorrectly rotated. How can I do this with WinEdt?

By the way, I already tried to write "-dAutoRotatePages=/None" into Options -> Execution Modes -> ps2pdf -> Executable -> Switches, but without success.

Comment: Related [How to set -dAutoRotatePages#/None in MikTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58325/how-to-set-dautorotatepages-none-in-miktex) and [PSTricks figure turned 90 degrees](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126859/pstricks-figure-turned-90-degrees). may be try `ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages#/None` instead of `ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages=/None`

Comment: Thanks a lot. In fact, that's a solution to my problem! ;-)